# I want to make link on values which will come from model in yii2 kartik Grid view. How can i do this?

Tags: yii2

```
$gridColumns = [
    [
        'attribute' => 'seller_name',
        'label' => 'Seller Name',
    ],
]
```

the value which will p[print under this will be a link

Comment: echo GridView::widget([
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'columns' => $gridColumns,
            'bootstrap' => true,
            'containerOptions' => ['style' => 'overflow: auto'], // only set when $responsive = false
            'headerRowOptions' => ['class' => 'kartik-sheet-style'],
            'responsiveWrap' => false,
            
        ]);
this is the index page.

Comment: the seller name which will come from table should be clickable

Comment: Avoid putting code in comments. Instead, edit the question to add the code and any additional information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use anonymous function and raw format

```
      <?= GridView::widget([
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'filterModel' => $searchModel,
        'columns' => $gridColumns
```

For $gridColumns

```
$gridColumns = [
    [
      'attribute' => 'seller_name',
      'label' => '#Seller Name',
      'format' => 'raw',
      'value' => function ($model) {                      
         return "<a href='". $model->your_link_field ."'   >Your Test for Link  </a>";
      },
   ],
]
```